# Не работает cUrl с поддоменом

Tags: php, curl, php7

Пытаюсь с основного домена (domain.ru) отправить cUrl запрос на поддомен (s1.domain.ru/path/to/script). Домены находятся на разных серверах. Проблема в том, что на локалке все работает (соответственно domain.local и s1.domain.local), но когда заливаю на сервер, то запрос до поддомена не доходит. В качестве вывода curl_exec() получаю 404 ошибку, стандартную. В тексте ошибки следующее:

> The requested URL /path/to/script was not found on this server.

Такое чувтсво, что скрипт с cUrl на основном домене обращается не на поддомен s1, а на самого себя (domain.ru/path/to/script).

Код:

```
     $ch = curl_init()
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 's1.domain.ru/path/to/script');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     $page = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
```

Перепробовал по всякому на разных примерах из интернета. На другие сайты запрос идет и все работает, не работает только с поддоменом.

Скрипт s1.domain.ru/path/to/script простро выводит "Hello World".

Вопрос в следующем: возможно в curl_setopt нужно что то специфическое указывать или все таки дело в сервере. Может есть какие-то настройки, из-за которых неработает запрос на поддомен. Сам склоняюсь ко второму, но даже не представляю, что это могут быть за настройки.

php 7, ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте какая ошибка:

```
 $ch = curl_init()
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.'s1.domain.ru/path/to/script');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $page = curl_exec($ch);
 if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
        print "Error: " . curl_error($ch); 
 }
 curl_close($ch);
```

PS: Если у вас https попробуйте для проверки отключить верификацию:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: Спасибо, действительно есть ошибка Error: Failed to connect to s1.domain.ru port 443: Connection refused. Буду гуглить в эту сторону. Отключение верификации ошибку не убирает.

Comment: может порт отключён на поддомене?

Comment: Врядли, так как на поддомен с локалки запросы проходять, не проходят только с основного сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема в том что не указывали схему http или https в начале url.
Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
$ch = curl_init()
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://s1.domain.ru/path/to/script');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Этот вариант тоже пробовал, в принципе с него и начал. Пробовал и с http и с https. По обоим адресам из браузера скрипт доступен.

Comment: В логах apache2 или nginx смотрели куда запрос идет и приходит ли он на ваш сервер?

Comment: Смотрел, запросы с основного домена до поддомена не доходят совсем.

Comment: А с локали на поддомен идут запросы? Вообще похоже что проблема не в curl

Comment: Да, с локалки на поддомен (и локальный, и глобальный) идут.

Comment: А если с сервера с консоли отправить "curl http ://s1.domain.ru/path/to/script" (http с пробелом, уберите его) какой ответ будет? Может с curl что на сервере

Comment: Yaroslav Molchan,  результат такой же, на http://... отдает 404 страницу, на https://... отдает ошибку curl: (7) Failed to connect to s1.domain.ru port 443: Connection refused

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55108/discussion-between-andrey-and-yaroslav-molchan).

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за ответы и потраченное время.

Проблему решил сам. Собственно, как обычно, сам ее и создал.

В панели управления сервером, был добавлен ip сервера поддомена (в ходе "экспериментов"), о чем я успешно забыл. Соответственно запрос шел не на сервер поддомена, а на собственный сервер.